# Calling rest api using Curl on Windows passing json

Tags: web-services, rest, curl

I have a rest API hosted on a Windows server. I have built an app to call it and it works perfectly. But, other people, need to call it using their own app and it is not working. I am trying to use curl to call it.

This is the Operation Contract in the api.

```
[DataContract]
public class ProjectList
{
    [DataMember]
    public string APIKey { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ProjectCentre { get; set; }

    public ProjectList(string apiKey, string projectCentre)
    {
    this.APIKey = apiKey;
    this.ProjectCentre = projectCentre;
    }
}
```

This is the Operation Contract

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
UriTemplate = "projectslist")]
List<Project> ProjectsList(ProjectList ProjectListObject);
```

And this is the method called.

```
public List<Project> ProjectsList(ProjectList ProjectListObject)
{
List<Project> myProjects = new List<Project>();
//code omitted here for clarity
//this just gets a list of projects and returns it 
return myProjects;
}
```

When I call it from my own client, written in C#, the request is created by ...

```
ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ProjectList));
MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
ser.WriteObject(mem, myProjectList);
string data = "{\"ProjectListObject\":" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray(), 0, (int)mem.Length) + "}";

// Create a byte array of the data we want to send 
byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString());

// Set the content length in the request headers
request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;
```

The string called data (above) contains this:

```
"{\"ProjectListObject\":{\"APIKey\":\"abcd1234\",\"ProjectCentre\":\"KL\"}}"
```

Calling it from my C# application it all works perfectly.

But, how can I call it using Curl?

I have tried putting the rest api into debug and using this command line:

```
C:\Temp\curl curl --insecure --request POST --header "Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8" --data @dataprojects.json http://localhost:65254/Register.svc/projectslist --include
```

But it returns an error - just says Request Error and 'The server encountered an error'.

The file dataprojects.json contains this:

```
{"ProjectListObject":{"APIKEY":"abcd1234","ProjectCentre":"KL"}}
```

I have tried a hundred different ways of formatting the curl command line to include the Project object as a json object - but nothing works. If I change my method so it takes no input parameter and call it using Curl, it works fine. But it will not let me pass the json object. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried typing the json data in the curl command instead of referring to it

Comment: Oh yes, I've tried everything. Of course as soon as you start down that route you are into escaping inverted commas etc. I got it to work using different syntax in the curl command line .. "Content-type:application/json" -X POST -d @dataprojects.json